# ios app analytics api/commandline

Tags: app-store-connect

Is there any API or command line tools for getting iOS application statistics? I did read about the Java [Reporter](https://help.apple.com/itc/appsreporterguide/) and Autoingestion tools but they are extensive enough in terms of reports. I need to get a report like every month how many users installed, uninstalled, where are they from, etc. There is some data in the sales report its not exactly what we are looking for. I am only concerned about usage and installation statistics and not sales or finance.